# Should I maintain my mindfulness 24 hours a day?

Tags: mindfulness, meditation-practicalities

I love mindfulness but when I sleep I loose all my mindfulness. I see dreams in which I am unaware of the Truth.

Should I maintain my mindfulness 24 hours a day?
If yes , how can I maintain my mindfulness 24 hours a day so that mindfulness extends into my sleep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mindfulness will increase with correct, consistent practice. At some point, if continued practice occurs, the sleep cycle will be affected too, in the form of a lighter sleep with less dreaming and more awareness.

When balancing the Five Spiritual Faculties, Mindfulness is the only factor that is not balanced meaning one can cultivate as much mindfulness as possible without creating any imbalances in the mind.

I would recommend watching the video [*"How Mindfulness Creates Understanding (The Buddhist TV)"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFqdlfeq7wE&feature=youtu.be) by Ven. Yuttadhammo.

Comment: What do you mean by "more awareness" during sleep?

Comment: @Val. Just increased mindfulness.

Comment: I agree with @Lanka. Science has shown through many studies (including this one: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3779833/) that the 'sleeping mind' seems to primarily exist to process thoughts and experiences originally gained from the 'waking mind'. This being the case, the more you can train your 'waking mind' to mindfulness in thoughts and experience, it would make sense that, over time, your 'sleeping mind' will be similarly fed with mostly mindful thoughts to process and aligned to mindfulness as well. Best.

Answer (score 3):

The better you get at mindfulness while you are awake, the less dreams you will see while you are asleep. When you go to sleep, take the lying posture as the primary object of meditation and practice mindfulness until you fall asleep. If you still keep dreaming on a daily basis, you should get advice on your meditation technique and get it readjusted.